# How to get a set of sets from text field?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to convert value from `textField.text`
to `Set<Set<Int?>>`

Example of string:`[nil],[1],[2],[1,2]`

Comment: Explain your working process. What is the possible inputs and how it need to work.

Comment: Inputs- integers and nill, program should at first get string from text field and then convert it to the type described above

Comment: Ins't clear. User must write data like: `1,2,3,5` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let string = "[nil],[1],[2],[1,2]"

var resultArray: [Set<Int?>] = []

for substring in string.split(separator: "[") {
    var set = Set<Int?>()
    var setString = String(substring)
    setString.removeLast(setString.last == "]" ? 1 : 2)
    for substring in setString.split(separator: ",") {
        set.insert(Int(substring))
    }
    resultArray.append(set)
}
print(resultArray)
// [Set([nil]), Set([Optional(1)]), Set([Optional(2)]), Set([Optional(2), Optional(1)])]
```